# Is there away to generate a unique machine hash in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to generate a unique ref for a user? Maybe based on machine ID, CPU/motherboard, or anything else which comes though which can be accessed server side from a webpage?

I am looking to see if I created a kind of Id based on a the machine without the need for a cookie.

Comment: What do you mean, "from a webpage"?  You mean server-side in ASP.NET?  Or client-side using javascript?

Comment: Server side, just not sure if its possable.

Comment: Use a cookie [15 chars].

Comment: I was looking for an altenative, dosnt have to be machine information just something thats sent via the header which can be joined / hashed to make a uniquie ref for a user. as about 5% of user have cookies turned off.

Comment: If a user has cookies turned off, tell them that, and inform that their use of the site will be greatly impaired without cookies on.  If you want to be extra nice, detect the browser and give them a link that tells them how.

Comment: So other than use cookies, is there another way.. thats all i want to know.

Comment: I think if you stated your ultimate goal of what this information does for you, you may not answer *this* question, but get some design ideas that may make the answer to this question no longer relevant. IOW, maybe you think you need to do something that is solved in an easier manner.

Comment: There's nothing you can implement that will work reliably.  You would need to create a random id on page load (in javascript) and modify every link on the page to include that id in the query string.  Still not reliable, because a user could simply delete the value in the querystring in order to be 'forgotten'.

Comment: If the user has cookies turned off then *they do not want you to uniquely identify them*. **Respect the stated privacy wishes of your users.** Do not attempt to defeat them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find this using ONLY webserver code or javascript client code, then you've found a security hole in a browser that should soon be patched.   By design, browsers limit information that is sent to the server or exposed to script.

You can either use a cookie, get the user to run some other code (you can use flash cookies, etc), or look at something like [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) (which is not nearly 100% reliable) or [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to glean some methods from [BrowserSpy](http://browserspy.dk/).

Answer (score 1):

A webpage will never have access to the computers hardware. You need a program to run locally on the machine (java, c++, c#..) with full trust to gain access to this ressources. Maybe you can also use a signed applet or ocx control, but most users won't accept that.

The information the browser sends to the server like user agent, language, installed plugins and IP address are the only information you have. They aren't guaranteed to be unique, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "not really".  Javascript does not directly provide any of the information you require, and I think you need to ask yourself why you need this info.

That said, for IE only, you could construct an ActiveX object that grabbed the necessary information and passed it out to javascript.  Wouldn't be compatible with other browsers/OS' though.  See the article [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/How-to-Use-JavaScript-for-Hardware-Knowledge/1/) to see an example of getting the processor details into javascript.